# Including libxml2 with a LLVM module map

Tags: swift, llvm, libxml2

When trying to build a Swift package I created that uses a LLVM module map to include libxml2 from `/usr/include/libxml2/`, I get the following error:

```
Compiling Swift Module 'foo' (1 sources)
<module-includes>2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2: 
#import "/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/catalog.h"

/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/catalog.h:22:10: error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
```

This is my module map:

```
module Clibxml2 [system] {

    umbrella "/usr/include/libxml2"
    export *
}
```

My dummy `main.swift` file only tries to import the module for now:

```
import Clibxml2
```

It compiles when I try to use another header path / umbrella (e.g. `/usr/include/CommonCrypto`). I verified that `xmlversion.h` does exist in `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but the reason it works for CommonCrypto but not libxml2 is that the libxml2 headers assume /usr/include/libxml2 is on the header search path, and use #include's of the form `#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>`. If you were building the module manually you could just pass `-I/usr/include/libxml2` to the swiftc invocation, but I suspect you're wanting this to work with `swift build`.

Comment: The CommonCrypto headers also assume CommonCrypto is in header search path. 
Using `/usr/include/libxml2` as umbrella path should add it as header search path, shouldn't it?

Comment: The CommonCrypto headers do things like `#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`. That works since /usr/include is in the search path by default. That's not the same as the libxml2 case, since that needs /usr/include/libxml2 to be in the search path. The documentation on the [`umbrella`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#umbrella-directory-declaration) declaration makes no mention of it altering the header search path.

Comment: See this Swift bug: [Need a way to add include paths in modulemap](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-145).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift has an [`-Xcc` option](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/commit/2e841e1bb4492116628f46523fe8f4ffd9eba4fc) now which can be used to pass additional compiler flags:

```
swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/libxml2
```